# Why sizeof(0.7)=8 bytes in c?

Tags: c, floating-point, size, double

I want to know that why sizeof(0.7) is 8 byte?

please explain?

thanks!

Comment: It is a double literal, obviously. On a majority of modern platforms, double is 8 bytes wide.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what were you expecting?

Comment: 0.7 is float and it can be of 4 byte

Comment: Floating point constants are double precision unless specified otherwise. Try `sizeof(0.7f);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `0.7` is a literal of type `double` and `double` has a size of 8 chars on your system.

Comment: Exactly. On most operating systems, a `double` is 8 bytes. On some, a `double` is 16 bytes however.

Answer (score 2):

because float literal is double?

Answer (score 1):

by default argument not `float` but `double`

Answer (score 1):

0.7 is saved as double, which on most platforms is 8 bytes.

For more Information, please have a look at the basic C Data Types, i.e. on Wikipedia [1] or other people [2].

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types
[2] http://rajkishor09.hubpages.com/hub/Data-Types-in-C-Language